# How do I Access an outer column within subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a list of all companies with the corresponding contact that is linked to the company. For arguments sake, I'll assume only one contact exists per company. I'm trying to use the following:

```
SELECT companies.id as company_id, contacts.name, contacts.email
FROM  companies, (SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE companyId = company_id LIMIT 1) as contacts
```

But I'm getting this error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'company_id' in 'where clause'

I've tried nearly every variation of aliasing the column itself and the tables but not having any luck all morning. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using full table names instead of aliases?

Comment: like companies.id? yep but I'm getting the same error. I've a feeling it could just be the wrong combination of aliases but I've been trying everything!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
SELECT cmp.id as company_id, 
      (SELECT name FROM contacts WHERE cmp.Id = company_id LIMIT 1)
FROM  companies cmp
```

Comment: sorry.. I should have mentioned I'll be wanting to get email address as well from the contact record. Question updated ^

Answer (score 0):

you can add email to your code if it is present in contacts table

```
 SELECT comp.id as company_id, 
  (SELECT name,email FROM contacts WHERE comp.Id = company_id LIMIT 1) FROM  companies comp
```

here email is the field name if you have different field name for the email value you can change it

do this

```
    SELECT comp.id as company_id, SELECT name,email FROM contacts WHERE comp.Id = company_id LIMIT 1 FROM  companies comp
```

Comment: I tried that but a subselect in that position can only contain one value: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)